# Excel Sub very slow at returning control

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple SUB within an Excel VBA module that runs almost instantly and gives control back to the user with no noticeable delay - but only when I run the sub from Excel's Alt-F8 list of public subs.

When I run the same sub by launching it from a button or shape then it still runs almost instantly BUT on finishing takes about 3 seconds to give control back to the user. The Windows busy circle icon displays on the screen during this pause and Excel does not respond to any key presses.

So, why can launchng a sub from a button be so different to launching from Alt-F8?

(I know that the sub itself runs very quickly as I have tested it with a Timer wrapper which confirms that the actual code runs in less than 0.1 seconds)

The code is shown here, but I would've thought this almost irrelevant as the same code is being run but just being launched by different means.

```
Public Sub RefDel()

IX = ActiveCell.Row: IY = ActiveCell.Column
If Cells(IX, 2) = "R" And (IY = PlnNor Or IY = PlnRef) Then
   II = MsgBox("Remove Reference?", 292, Cells(IX, PlnRef))
   If II = vbYes Then
      ProtOff
      NOF = Cells(IX, PlnNor)
      Rows(IX & ":" & IX + NRoRef - 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
      Do While Cells(IX, 2) = "R" ' Renumber subsequent rows
         Cells(IX, PlnNor) = NOF
         NOF = NOF + 1
         IX = IX + NRoRef
      Loop
      Cells(IX - NRoRef, PlnRef).Select
      ProtOn
   End If
Else
   MsgBox "Select a Reference", vbCritical, "Delete Reference"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Use variant array instead of constantly referencing the worksheet.

Comment: I would often use a variant array but in this case the range is only 1-20 iterations of the loop and only has this delay when run from a button. The same code has no delay when run from Alt-F8. I'll try a variant array and see if it helps but I'm not sure why it should.

Comment: Make sure you declare the parent worksheet for every range and cell object.  you should also get in the habit of declaring all you variables so excel does not try to guess.

Comment: All my variables are declared at the module level in this case and none of them are variant. All this code ony ever runs in the context of this active sheet so I have omitted full sheet referencing.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  For me, control is return instantly when executed from a shape.

Comment: I have also not experienced this before and have tested another shape and button on a different sheet and I cannot reproduce it either. There's clearly something odd about the original context but I can't get my head around the fact that it runs instantly if I use the Alt-F8 list.

I think I'll have to engineer it out for now. I'll try this action from a right-click instead.

Comment: If I run it via the Worksheet_BeforeRightClick event then there it runs instantly with no delay before returning control. ????? This at least gives me a fix but makes the user interface a bit less obvious. Thanks for testing things. If I find a solution rather than a workaround then I'll share it here.